# Relation of root length to plant size

Tags: botany

I am thinking of making an aeroponics system.
But after i finished my primary design I though to myself how deep should I make the container for the roots of my plants? Since I want to make my system applicable to a range of plants image from microgreens to lettuce. I was thinking how can I determine the size of the roots of the desired plants? I there a way to determine this from the size of the plant or not?

This would be important since if the container is too small the spriklers my get covered my the roots of some plants. And if the container is too big some roots my not get enough water. Next to this a more space efficient container would be better (So it also looks a bit nice)

I am a complete newbie to this so please let me know if any clarification is needed :) And if this is even the right place to ask.

Comment: Root length is something that plants change in response to their environment.

Comment: Ok, so let's say the environment for the roots is very optimal would that result in longer or shorter roots?

Comment: Compare, for example, root system depth for trees such as oaks vs the Welwitschia plant of southern Africa...